# MapServer Runtime Substitution Error

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, mapserver

I'm trying to perform pgRouting with MapServer so I've created a function in PostGIS and the call it in map file with runtime substitution. The DATA part is as follows:

```
DATA "geom FROM (SELECT * FROM routing_func(%source% , %target%)) AS foo USING UNIQUE seq using srid=2100"
```

My validation section in the map file is:

```
   VALIDATION 
        "source" "[0-9]+"
         "target" "[0-9]+"
   END
```

and the CLASS object:

```
CLASS
        NAME 'routing'
        EXPRESSION "%source% && %target%"
        STYLE
            COLOR 255 0 0
            WIDTH 4
       END
   END
```

I try to pass the parameters in map mode with the following request:

```
 http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/user/mapdata/mapfile.map&mode=map&source=90&target=900
```

but nothing is drawn for the route that was supposed to be calculated.

If I try the OpenLayers template like:

```
   http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/user/mapdata/mapfile.map&template=openlayers&source=90&target=900
```

The MS_ERRORFILE gives me the following error:

```
Error (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ...d, source, target, time as cost FROM roads_noded',%source%,%...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EXPRESSION part looks a little funny.  Why do you need that?

First of all, I think you need a CLASSITEM which would be a filed to match against. Even then you "%source% && %target%" doesn't make sense.

What happens if you remove that.

Regarding your validation, I think it should work, however to insure only digits are in string, I would do instead:

```
VALIDATION
    'source' '^[0-9]+$'
    'target' '^[0-9]+$'
END
```

Comment: When you say "Why do I need the expression" you mean it really doesn't need to be there or it's malformed? I thought that the expression says what should be substituted. Yeah I had a hunch about the CLASSITEM but I'm not sure what should I put there...

Comment: The variable name tells what should be substituted. If depends on the use case where to use substitution but you have it in DATA and I suppose that it is enough. Draw everything that gets selected and no classitem nor expression should be needed.

Comment: I removed classitem and expression and only left VALIDATION as indicated in the answer ("source" "^[0-9]+$"). I'm trying it minimally at the moment so I leave a random number in the target variable and only substitute the source  putting a number in the url like &source=12.   Unfortunately I still get the same error:    Error (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ...hex') as geom,"seq" from (SELECT * FROM _a_router(%source%, ...

Comment: It's almost as if your validation rules are being ignored.  Where did you put the VALIDATION .. END.  In your layer definition I presume?  If not put it in  as part of your layer definition.  I should add I've only used mapserver with SERVICE=WMS and variable substitution has worked for me.  I presume it should work in mode=map as well, though haven't tried.

Comment: One other question just to rule out you are using a version that doesn't support substitution.  What does mapserv -v  (run that on command line) return?

Comment: My MapServer version is 7.0.1 which I compiled with cmake.  mapserv -v gives the following: MapServer version 7.0.1 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=XMP SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
Yes, validation is in the layer level, as well as CONNECTIONTYPE and DATA.

Comment: huh... when I try it with SERVICE=WMS and pass the source and target in the end, it indeed returns a static image with the route. If I try it in map mode which again returns a static image and pass the params. it works too. In browse mode we have a problem. If I try like the first time of invocation it returns the route. But when I try to zoom in I get the same error,  regarding the % sign

Comment: Is it possible your zoom logic is stripping out the params?  What are you using for your map viewer?

Comment: The link I use to perfom it is:localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=home/user/mapdata/mapfile.map&template=openlayers. I believe it's normal not work somehow since this openlayers template is fixed and pulled from a third party server in this occasion so the source and target values are never put in the Openlayers script. On the other hand maybe it should work without any result and not throw errors. According to the docs: if what you pass isn't evaluated there's only a slight performance in mapserver... (?)

Comment: No it errors out so it not being included in url would explain it.  Because then it doesn't get replaced.  I think to force replace even if you don't pass values, you need to specify a default value to use in the map file.  It's written in the substitution docs, I forget the syntax.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I pass in as "source_default" and "target_default" the value of 1 so there is no line drawn. Thank you much. I think this small hack solves the problem so far